# Get absolute path of a file via classpath in Maven project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have looked at posts here and searched around for an answer to this question and couldn't find a whole lot ( probably due to my lack of knowledge with Java/Maven ). Anyways, I have a Maven project where I store some files in the resources folder at /src/main/resources.  If I try to access them via this method:

```
getClass.getResources("/myfile.txt").getFile ();
```

I will get the following path:

```
/home/myUsername/projectFolder/target/myProject-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/myfile.txt
```

What I am wondering is how can I retrieve the absolute path without the " /target/myProject-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar! " ?

Comment: Why do you need the absolute path of it? Cause it's located inside a JAR file?

Comment: Certain other libraries require an absolute path to a file that I am using.  The files I wish to keep within the application itself. For example I have .fxml files because I'm using java fx.

Comment: Have you packaged that file into your jar file? If so it is not possible cause as I already mentioned inside the JAR file...If you like to keep it outside the jar you need to put it somewhere else...and define the path to it hard coded or user based...

Comment: Why is it not possible?  Is it because you can't get the full path from within the java application at runtime?

Comment: If you are inside a JAR file it does not have an absolute path cause you are inside a JAR and not on a file system...